# Any idea"ERROR/QemuSensors(13441): data__poll: len=-1, errno=9: Bad file number"

Tags: android, android-sensors

I have an ANDROID application which reads sensor values and writes them to a .csv file.The file writing runs on a continous thread.The thread is terminated on a button press.Everything is fine but I keep getting an error **"QemuSensor:data_poll:len=-1,errorno=9:Bad file number".Anyone has seen it before.**

Comment: which sensor is it? and where is the .csv file

Comment: Same here, appear when I use Accelerometer sensor in Emulator.

Comment: Did you figure out the reason yet? I am not doing anything with Accelerometer but getting the same error when I close it.

Answer (score 0):

it happens because you are testing in emulator test in real android device.
your code will sure work.